# Use Python And OpenCV To Read From A Seven Segmented Display

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to make a python program that can read digits from a seven segmented red led display.  I will put some examples of what I am trying to process.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np 

def color_filter(img):
    """Filters out only red-to-white color"""
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_red = np.array([0, 0, 200])
    upper_red = np.array([60, 255, 255])
    mask_1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

    lower_red = np.array([150, 0, 200])
    upper_red = np.array([255, 255, 255])
    mask_2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    
    result = 255*(mask_1 + mask_2)
    result = result.clip(0, 255).astype("uint8")

    return cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=result)
```

The program needs to read the digits displayed in the LCD display like from the images above.  Till now I have wrote a color filtering code.  My question is now that I have filtered the text out, How do I read it. I have tried using tesseract OCR, but it simply doesn't work.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: "Simply doesn't work" means nothing to me.  *Why* does it not work?  What are the results you're getting when using Tesseract?

Comment: by not working I mean in most of the the images, it simply does not output something, or detect something. And In images where it does, it output wrong digits, or it just detect one or two digits